# How can I get the value of the next input element?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<li class="order_line">
  <div class="rating">
    <input type="textbox" value="10" maxlength="3" class="store_rating" name="item_rating"> 
  </div>
  <div class="cost">
    <input type="textbox" readonly="readonly" value="469" maxlength="3" class="store_cost" name="item_rating">
  </div>
</li>
```

The closest I get is using this code:

```
var cost = $(this).parent().next().html();
```

An `alert(cost)` will ouput the entire `<input...` string.

But I'm not able to get the value.

I've found several similar problems (that's how I almost got the solution), but I'm not able to complete the last steps.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var cost = $(this).parent().next().find("input").val();`

You need to search within the parent `div` to find the `input`, and then get the value using `val()`

Or if you only have two, like in the example above, you could use something like:

`$("input").not(this).val()`

Answer (score 0):

`.parent()` gets you to a `<div>` element, and `.next()` gets you to the next `<div>`.  You want the child of that `<div>` which is an `<input>`.